# where_in just return 1 row

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

i have this code :

models (Mproses.php) :

```
function cari($d,$p)
{
        $this->db->select('cf_pakar,gejala');
        $this->db->from('gejalapenyakit');
        $this->db->where_in('id_gejala',$d);
        $this->db->where('id_penyakit',$p);

    return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

$d = ('1','2','3','4','5')

$p = 1

i have db with 30 row, 
when i run this code, i just got 1 row instead 5 row, i try my query from mysql and its return 5 row not just 1 row.

Comment: when im using echo $this->db-last_query().
the result : 
SELECT * FROM `gejalapenyakit` WHERE `id_gejala` IN('1','2','3','4','5') AND `id_penyakit` = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with that :

```
function cari($d,$p)
{
    $this->db->select('cf_pakar,gejala');
    $this->db->from('gejalapenyakit');
    $this->db->where('id_penyakit',$p);
    $this->db->where_in('id_gejala',$d);


return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

And your `$d = ('1','2','3','4','5')` should be `$d = ['1','2','3','4','5']`

try to do that :

```
function cari($d,$p)
{
    //load $d here with that :
    $d = ['1','2','3','4','5'];
    //or that :
    $d = [1,2,3,4,5]
    $this->db->select('cf_pakar,gejala');
    $this->db->from('gejalapenyakit');
    $this->db->where('id_penyakit',$p);
    $this->db->where_in('id_gejala',$d);


return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

if it works then your problem comes from your $d. If it's not, your problem must come from your db

Comment: if i use your code, then my first array will be on [0] right?, i think my $cf didnt need array, cause its just for displaing final result on view.

Comment: even if your function return 4 result at each loop $cf will take the new value so in the final $cf will give you one value. You need to store your 4 value somewhere to send it

Comment: what i ask is, why my query just return 1 row from database, not 5

Comment: @alandsamuel try with that

Answer (score 0):

You need to send ',' seperated values in query.

$d = implode(",",$d);

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

Answered :

Initially i use foreach to make my :

```
$input = $this->input->post('input');
$i = 0;
foreach($input as $i){
$i++;
$d = $d.$i.',';
$d = ('1','2','3','4','5');
```

and when i use $input for parameter, its work perfectly